# Tkinter doesn't stop execution even after closing the window

Tags: python, tkinter

In this code I am displaying a window with a label and two buttons, the user can read the file path currently in use in the label and decide if he wants to change it or continue with the buttons.

If he wants to change the path then I change the value inside the *textvariable* inside the label. The issue is when I do this for example 3 times, then I have to kill the program manually pressing CTRL + C 3 times. If I do it once then I only need to do it once, like there is something preventing the program to terminate. Thanks for the help.

```
def select_file():
    #OPEN TKINTER DIALOG LETTING ME TO CHOOSE A FILE AND RETURNS ITS PATH.
    tkinter.Tk().withdraw()  # prevents an empty tkinter window from appearing
    folder_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    return folder_path


def change_file():
    file_path = select_file()
    with open(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/Squad Generator/excel_file_path.txt'), 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_path)
    #WRITES THE FILE PATH IN THE VARIABLE AND CHANGES THE LABEL
    var.set(file_path)

def homepage():

    app.geometry("450x200")
    app.title("Squad Generator")

    label_1 = tkinter.Label(master=app, justify=tkinter.LEFT,textvariable=var, font = 
       ("JetBrains Mono", 15))
    label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")


    button1 = tkinter.Button(master=app, text="Continua", command=main)
    button1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")
    
    #BUTTON CAUSING THE ISSUE.
    button2 = tkinter.Button(master=app, command=change_file, text="Cambia file")
    button2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=20, sticky="ew")
    
    #CREATING APP MAINLOOP
    app.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tkinter.Tk()
    var = tkinter.StringVar(None, check_path_file())
    homepage()
```

Comment: Why are you destroying the application instance instead of just updating the existing file path / label / etc.? This seems cumbersome. Also, FWIW, you don't need `f.close()` in `change_file()` if you are using a context manager (the `with` block)

Comment: @JRiggles thanks for your input, I changed my code and now I just update the label, altough it still won't close

Comment: Would you mind updating the code here so we can see what's been changed?

Comment: @JRiggles ofc, I just did. Sorry for the delay

Comment: I see the problem now. Your `select_file` function is creating a separate instance of `Tk` (in addition to the one instantiated by `app`). This is why it's not closing - you're destroying the `app` instance, but not the other one created by `tkinter.Tk().withdraw()`

Comment: @JRiggles thank you, could you tell me more tho? How can I close that instance?

Comment: See my answer below - I think that should be a workable solution. When your app opens, it will prompt the user to select a file name. If they don't, the label will fall back to 'Select a file path'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reorganized your application a bit. I've wrapped everything in a basic class named `App` which serves as the root of your application. This should work as expected and keep everything contained within a single instance of `Tk`.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename


class App(tkinter.Tk):  # the App class inherits from Tk
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  # initialize Tk
        self.geometry("450x200")
        self.title("Squad Generator")

        self.label_var=tkinter.StringVar(self, 'Select a file path')

        self.label_1 = tkinter.Label(
            master=self,
            justify=tkinter.LEFT,
            textvariable=self.label_var,
            font=("JetBrains Mono", 15)
        )
        self.label_1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, padx=20, pady=(20, 0), sticky="nsew")

        self.button1 = tkinter.Button(master=self, text="Continua", command=main)
        self.button1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=20, pady=20, sticky="ew")
    
        self.button2 = tkinter.Button(
            master=self,
            command=self.change_file,
            text="Cambia file"
        )
        self.button2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=0, pady=20, sticky="ew")

        self.change_file()  # call this function when the app starts

    def change_file(self):
        file_path = askopenfilename()
        if file_path:  # if a file is selected and not cancelled by the user
            input_file = '~/Documents/Squad Generator/excel_file_path.txt'
        
            with open(os.path.expanduser(input_file), 'w') as f:
                f.write(file_path)  # write out 'file_path' to the 'input_file'
    
            #WRITES THE FILE PATH IN THE VARIABLE AND CHANGES THE LABEL
            self.label_var.set(file_path)
        else:
            self.label_var.set('Select a file path')  # fallback text if user cancels
  

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()  # instantiate your App class
    app.mainloop()  # run the app
```

If you're not familiar with classes, the word `self` here can be confusing. All you need to know is that `self` refers to the `App` class. So any widgets you define within that class, like `button1` have `self` as their master - i.e., they are children of the `App` class!

Also, any methods you define within the class (like `change_file(self)`) will be callable within the class via `self.change_file`, and will have access to any variables in the class, like `self.label_var`!

Comment: `change_file()` should be `self.change_file()` inside `__init__()`.

Answer (score -1):

From what I see you just did

> app.destroy()

But you actually need to do

> app.master.destroy()

With the first line you're just destroying the current frame, not the the top level container.

Comment: I tried, but I got `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'`

Comment: `App` is initially an instance of `Tk`, which has no `master`.